# Browser behavior for support "Same Origin Policy"

Tags: browser, web

Do all the browsers implement "Same Origin Policy" by generating a exception (error) when javascript try to visit a frame whose domain is different from current one?

I saw this in IE, Firefox and Chrome, but when I browse a page in IE with Chrome Frame plugin, it just warn and return a null. 
I'm really curious about this, can the user define the behavior of browser for SOP by setting warn or error? how many ways are there for browsers deal with the cross domain visit?

Comment: Very informativ:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 0):

Now all browsers support this policy.
Only older versions are missing from support.